# DO loops to update allocation SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops

I am working on a clinical trial where I have to create a variable for allocation(Zjt) based on the variable (Xjk) and T,K(Treatments=1,2,3) and Age Factor(J=1,2,3). We are assuming that if a patient falls in age factor(j) then it can be assigned K treatments(1,2,3). So if patient is in age factor one then patient can get assigned X11, X12,X13. Factor two(X21,X22,X33). Factor 3(X31,X32,X33). Z is the variable that keeps the count for each assigned treatment. T and K are both treatments used in different scenarios.
The sample data looks like this:

```
Subject J K  T X
1       1 2  2 X12
2       2 2  2 X22
3       1 1  1 X11
4       2 1  1 X21
..............
2310    1 3 X13

data four;
set four;    
If J = 1 and K=1 then X=X11
If J=2   and K=1 then X=X21 
If J=3   and K=2 then X=X32
data four;
set four;
If J=1 and T=1 then Z11=X11+1 Z12=X12 Z13=X13
If J=1 and T=2 then Z11=X11   Z12=X12+l Z13=X13
If J=1 and T=3 then Z11=X11   Z12=X12   Z13=X13+1
If J=2 and T=1 then Z21=X21+1 Z22=X22   Z23=X23
If J=2 and T=2 then Z21=X21   Z22=X22+1 Z23=X23
If J=2 and T=3 then Z21=X21   Z22=X22   Z23=X23+1
```

then it repeats for factor 3.

Each time T=K the Z(count for Xjk) increases by 1, if T is not equal to K then Z remains the same. I think I would need an array to check the condition each time and have no idea how to do it as I am very new to SAS. I have no idea how to program the Z as the arrays I have created have failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `z11=x11+1` mean?  is `x11` a variable?  Or are you just saying that `z11` contains the count of records that have `x11`?

Comment: I am sorry I meant z11 contains the count of records that have x11.

Comment: I think this still isn't very clear what you're doing.  How is this different from just a normal frequency?

Comment: if t=k the normal frequency increase by 1. So in this case the it would be the counts of records that have x11+1 so an extra 1 would be added each time.

Comment: Please show an example input data and expected output for that input.  Please show the examples as data steps that can run to eliminate confusion. For example in your first table is the variable X numeric or character? Are the values like X12 in the sample table the string `'X12'` or a place holder for some number or variable reference?

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you are making this much too complex. (or else I do not understand the question.)

It sounds like you have a list of subjects, what age group they are in and what two treatment groups they were assigned to. So it sounds like you have data like this:

```
data have ;
  input Subj AgeGrp Trt1 Trt2 ;
cards;
1  1 2  2
2  2 2  2
3  1 1  1
4  2 1  1
;
```

You could just use PROC FREQ to count how many fall into each combination.

```
proc freq data=have; tables trt1*trt2 ; run;
```

If you want the counts separately for each age group then add that variable also.

```
proc freq data=have; tables agegrp*trt1*trt2 ; run;
```